# How to make condition with using transition position at Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to make the simulation of traffic light, if the car position at x=100, y=100 and the light is red, the car moving slowly and stop at position x=120, y=120.

I use that script :

```
local function loopcar()
  car.x =430
   car.y=300
    transition.to(car, { x=0,y=50,time=3000,tag="mycar", onComplete=function()

      car.x =430
      car.y=300
      transition.to(car, { x=0,y=50,time=3000,tag="mycar", onComplete=loopcar } )
    end } )
end -- for looping the car
```

and I don't know how ta make condition that chek position when that object moving.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want achieve. Probably you can use [`enterFrame`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/enterFrame/index.html) listener to check position of car.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to ask, but transition.to returns a id to the transition so you could do:

```
car.animation = transition.to(car, { x=0,y=50,time=3000,tag="mycar", onComplete=function()
    car.animation = nil
end})
```

So to check if the car is currently moving you would do:

```
if (car.animation ~= nil)
    print("Car is moving")
else
    print("Car is NOT moving")
end
```

Hope this helps!